# Pushing object in localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, javascript-objects, saving-data

First of all, please, don`t try to understand why i'm trying to save passwords in localStorage, i just want to know if it possible.

So, I have a registration form, if localStorage is clear  - I save object in localStorage. If one object(s) is already in localStorage, i want to get this object(s), push them in array, and then push the brand new object in this array. Then set this Array in localStorage.

```
const registrationForm = document.getElementById('registration');
   registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let regName = document.querySelector(".registration__name").value;
      let regPassword = document.querySelector(".registration__password").value;
      let regEmail = document.querySelector(".registration__email").value;
      let clientObj = {
         name : regName,
         password: regPassword,
         email: regEmail
      };
      let clientsArr = [];
      clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Користувачі'));
      if(!clientsArr) {
         localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(clientObj));
      } else {
         clientsArr.push(clientObj);
         localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
      }
   })
```

Is this possible? Using this code, every time i create new array, and push it in array and again and again...

Comment: You're reading `Користувачі` and writing `Users`....

Answer (score 4):

Try the below

```
const registrationForm = document.getElementById('registration');
   registrationForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let regName = document.querySelector(".registration__name").value;
      let regPassword = document.querySelector(".registration__password").value;
      let regEmail = document.querySelector(".registration__email").value;
      let clientObj = {
         name : regName,
         password: regPassword,
         email: regEmail
      };
      let clientsArr = [];
      if(!localStorage.getItem('Users')) {
         clientsArr.push(clientObj);
         localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
      } else {
         clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users'));
         clientsArr.push(clientObj);
         localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
      }
   })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate and say what you have changed?

Comment: He was accessing a different local storage value and and adding data to another local storage value

Comment: it doesnt work, cause when the code 
`clientsArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users'));` exisited,` typeof clientsArr  === objec't. So i can't `clientsArr.push()`

Comment: change the if condition to this if(!localStorage.getItem('Users')) {
         clientsArr.push(clientObj);
         localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
      }

Answer (score 1):

You should always set the localStorage to an array:

```
   let clientsArr =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];
   clientsArr.push(clientObj);
   localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(clientsArr));
```

Comment: Thanks @jonas, it works